# Dyld error while running bundled Qt Designer in Anaconda (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, anaconda

I have the most recent version of anaconda installed and noticed that Qt Designer is included (`anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.7-1/bin`). However when trying to run it using terminal, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Me/Applications/anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.7-1/lib/libQtGui.4.8.7.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I tried to update the dynamic library search path as well, but now I get the following error:

```
# DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Me/Applications/anaconda/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ./qt-4.8.7-1/bin/Designer.app/Contents/MacOS/Designer

dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
Referenced from:  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
Expected in: /Users/Me/Applications/anaconda/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Is there a way to successfully run the bundled Qt Designer?